# Fetching photos uploaded by a user

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, joomla

I have used the Facebook graph link in my site, I have tried for the last two days but I am not able to fix this problem. For two months this code has been working fine but right now it is not working.

Here is the Link

```
https://graph.facebook.com/157705150944797/photos/uploaded
```

Why do I get this error?

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

But when I use the following link I will get a response

```
https://graph.facebook.com/157705150944797/photos/

{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "212708942111084",
         "from": {
            "category": "Local business",
            "category_list": [
               {
                  "id": "206284062724685",
                  "name": "Roofer"
               }
            ],
            "name": "Blue Sky Roofing, Inc.",
            "id": "157705150944797"
         },
         "picture": "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-e.ak/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/p130x130/284949_212708942111084_583574_n.jpg?oh=3554b061f512bb97cb577049578d5532&oe=54D26E47&__gda__=1427888341_67dd755838624aa1e322faa03d8e4325",
         "source": "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-e.ak/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/284949_212708942111084_583574_n.jpg?oh=8e26df9a434160f154dc0a4ad6690fad&oe=54D99C4B&__gda__=1424573780_940c191fc86f99e5316f39a70336606c",
         "height": 445,
         "width": 445,
         "images": [
            {
               "height": 445,
               "width": 445,
               "source": "https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/sphotos-e.ak/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/284949_212708942111084_583574_n.jpg?oh=8e26df9a434160f154dc0a4ad6690fad&oe=54D99C4B&__gda__=1424573780_940c191fc86f99e5316f39a70336606c"
            },
            ...
```

I don't know why I get that error when I use this link. I want to get all the uploaded photos in the site.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/157705150944797/photos/uploaded
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=157705150944797%2Fphotos%2Fuploaded&version=v2.0). Are you certain that this request is yielding the error?

Comment: Hi I didn't use any of the API. I just used directly used the link in the code. Two months back the code is working fine. Certainly its not working now. Please tell me have to use any of the API. if so, please tell me how to use.

Comment: I would recommend that you use an official SDK to access Facebook's API.

Comment: Same link I have used in browser means I will get this error {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
} But the link you are provided is working fine in google API explorer.. What is the problem?